# Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'. Property 'a' is missing in type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm a very beginner in TypeScript and now I'm trying to understand how interfaces works in a Class Method of React Component. I created a simple case for it, but it does not work. I always gets an error like in this post title.

I'll be pleased for any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

interface A {
  a: any[]
}

class Test extends Component {
  _getName = (a: A) => {
    return a
  }
  render() {
    const a = []
    return (
      <div>{this._getName(a)}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Does `[]` implement interface `A`?

Comment: `_getName` is expecting an object with property `a` as `any[]`. You are just passing `any[]`. So it will throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this._getName(a)` expects `a` to be of type `A`. `A` is defined as an object with a property `a` that is of type `any[]`. Your call-time `a` inside `render` is of type `[]`.

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to accomplish with this code but I guess what you want is to say that the parameter `a` in `_getName` should be of type `any[]`? Then you probably need `type A = any[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain, please, why would we use the `type` alias, instead of `interface` directly? Thanks

Comment: Types and Interfaces are different in many ways. One of them is that Interfaces can not describe things like `number`, `boolean`, `any[]`, `string[]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface A {
  a: any[]
}
```

means that the object that implements the interface "A" is required to have a property called "a" that will be of type "any[]" (array of any type)

but here:

```
const a = []
```

it looks like a is just an empty array - not an object, thus not having properties

In my opinion you don't need an interface here. Try instead:

```
  _getName = (a: any[]) => {
    return a
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to do so:

```
class Test extends Component {
  _getName = (a: A) => {
    return a.a;
  }
  render() {
    const a = {a: []};
    return this._getName(a);
  }
}
```